# HTML file not opening in executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have a program I have written in Eclipse and it runs fine -- the HTML file opens when I run the program through Eclipse. But when I create a jar file of the program, everything else runs fine except this HTML file won't open in the browser (or anywhere):

```
    operation.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                File htmlFile = new File("help/operation.html");
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
            } catch (MalformedURLException MURLe) {
                MURLe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioE) {
                ioE.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The rest of the program runs fine, and my images and sounds work fine and are opened, but this HTML file will not open in the menu or with the Ctrl+key shortcut. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should read file as stream

Comment: Was it working before deploying (without jar file)?

Comment: Its either: 1. the default directory of the application is different when running the JAR, vs the eclipse project. 2. the .html is inside the jar, and you are expecting the File class will find it, which is never going to happen as its compiled into the jar.

Comment: @afzalex yes it worked in Eclipse. I could open the html file.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a file inside your jar, you cannot access it like you are doing now.
You need to **read it as a stream**, that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your project is `foo`. Then `help/operation.html` will refer to
**..\abc\help\operation.html**

But the deployed jar file will not contain it.
You have include this `operation.html` file in your source code (where you write code).
Then eclipse (or any IDE) will add it into your jar file when you deploy it.

And now you can use your file as follows.
Suppose your file is present in as shown in figure.
[image]
Now you can refer your html file from any class. In this example referring it from
`Accesser` class.

```
File resFile = new File(Accesser.class.getResource("operation.html").toURI());
```

If you want to open your file in browser you will have to copy this file into the
user's System.

```
File htmlFile = new File("operation.html");
if(!htmlFile.exists) {
    Files.copy(resFile.toPath(), htmlFile.toPath());
}
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
```

*Files is present in `java.nio.file` package*

Comment: but will Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI()); be able to access the file?

Comment: Browser cannot read any file from zipped file. He will need to copy that file to system if he wanted to use this file in browser.

Comment: Then the above answer should be working for you, and will work same on any other computer, without needing you to copy any file there. @btalbot